# "Order" doesn't work in custom loop?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I have a custom loop (used in a shortcode) that lists items from custom post type.

Everything works fine but "order" for posts doesn't work, no matter what I type as order attribute on post page - items are always displayed the same way (the most recent first and the oldest last).

Why doesn't "order" work in my case?

The loop looks like:

```
  $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type' => 'images',   
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
         ) );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
(my code)
php endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `orderby` clause to your query! Here is the complete list of [order parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

```
 $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type' => 'images',   
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
         ) );
```

This query order by the menu order that you have specified in your pages